# using jquery animate inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I just have a `div` with the *`background color`* covering the entire view called "*colorPanel*" (using html id).

This code does not run and I don't understand why.

When I change `col` to `$col`, it still does not run.

What am I not understanding about jquery?

```
function animateColors(i){
    var val = 1/0.2*(i) * 210;
    var col = 'hsla('+val+', 90%, 60%, 1)';
    $("#colorPanel").animate({"background-color": col}, 200);
    i = (i<180)? i+4 : 0;
    animateColors(i);
}

animateColors();
```

Comment: You arent passing anything to the initial call to `animateColors()`. Is this a typeo? If not `i` is undefined for the initial run of the program. Also there is no terminating condition for your recursive function.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), "The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property." and "For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used". Depending on your requirements, you could just use a CSS transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Already @brut & @tiantang suggest the valid point as comment. please consider that.
>
> You arent passing anything to the initial call to animateColors(). Is this a typeo? If not i is undefined for the initial run of the program. Also there is no terminating condition for your recursive function.
>
> From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), "The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property." and "For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used". Depending on your requirements, you could just use a CSS transition.

As per those comments I will make changes on your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animateColors(i){
        var val = 1/0.2*(i) * 210;
        var col = 'hsla('+val+', 90%, 60%, 1)';
        $("#colorPanel").css({"background-color": col});
        i = (i<180)? i+4 : 0;
        // animateColors(i); // when using this too much recursion error occur
        setTimeout( function(){animateColors(i)}, 500);
    }
    animateColors(1);
});
```

```css
#colorPanel {
  height: 20px; /*your wish*/
  width: 100%; /*your wish*/
  transition: all ease 0.5s; /*for animation effect*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorPanel"></div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This will work! Thank you. I did not realize you could not run random jquery lines in javascript without document ready. I will look for into how jquery works.